# HashMap en java, error contando elementos

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo este método que debe devolver el nombre del plato de un restaurante con la cantidad de veces que se encuentra en total de todos los restaurantes. Si el  plato esta retorna 1, si esta mas de una vez debe contar y retornar esas veces. pero solo me esta devolviendo máximo 2 veces y si aumento la cantidad sigue contando 2. ¿Qué está mal?

class Restaurante {

```
String nombre;
String direccion;
int capacidad;
LinkedList<String> platosMenu;

public static HashMap<String, Integer> cuentaPlatos(LinkedList<Restaurante> 
 lista) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> mapa = new HashMap();
    ListIterator<Restaurante> it = lista.listIterator();
    int cont = 1; 
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Restaurante clave = it.next();
        LinkedList<String> platos = clave.getPlatosMenu();
        for(String plato : platos){
            if(mapa.containsKey(plato)){
                mapa.put(plato,cont+1);
            }else{
                mapa.put(plato,cont);
            }}}
    return mapa;
```

Main--------------

```
    Restaurante{nombre=Restaurante1, direccion=Sur, capacidad=50, 
    platosMenu=[guatita, encebollado, arroz con menestra]}

    Restaurante{nombre=Restaurante2, direccion=Centro, capacidad=85, 
    platosMenu=[encebollado, arroz con menestra, caldo de bola]}

    Restaurante{nombre=Restaurante3, direccion=Este, capacidad=100, 
    platosMenu=[guatita, pescado frito, encebollado, arroz con menestra]}

    Retorno:
    ( encebollado y arroz con menestra deberian retornar 3 )
    guatita - 2
    encebollado - 2
    caldo de bola - 1
    arroz con menestra - 2
    pescado frito - 1
```

Comment: Lo que está mal posiblemente (entre cosas) es la forma en que llenas tu mapa. ¿Dónde está el código en que introduces valores al mapa?

Comment: listaR.add(new Restaurante("Restaurante1","Sur",50, rest_1));
             listaR.add(new Restaurante("Restaurante2","Centro",85, rest_2));
             listaR.add(new Restaurante("Restaurante3","Este",100, rest_3));
        
             for(Restaurante elemento : listaR)
                        System.out.println(elemento);
             for(String clave : cuentaPlatos(listaR).keySet()){
                        System.out.println(clave+" - "+
           (cuentaPlatos(listaR).get(clave)));
           }

Comment: No veo por ningún lado donde agregas los platos que hay en cada restaurante, que es lo que quieres comparar según lo planteado en la pregunta y según lo que intentas en tu código. ¿Cómo agregas los platos a las restaurantes?

Comment: rest_1.add("guatita");
        rest_1.add("encebollado");
        rest_1.add("arroz con menestra");
        
        rest_2.add("encebollado");
        rest_2.add("arroz con menestra");
        rest_2.add("caldo de bola");
        
        rest_3.add("guatita");
        rest_3.add("pescado frito");
        rest_3.add("encebollado");
        rest_3.add("arroz con menestra");


 Aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es obvio que tu intención es de ir agregando `1` al valor que vas guardando en tu mapa. Pero en realidad, eso no es lo que haces. El problema es que nunca lees el valor que tiene el mapa, solo le asignas `cont` o `cont + 1`, lo que equivale a `1` o `2`. Nota que aparte de la sentencia `int cont = 1;`, nunca le asignas un valor a la variable `cont`.

Si simplificamos el código y aplicamos lo que era tu intención de ir acumulando la cuenta, se puede lograr de la manera siguiente:

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> cuentaPlatos(LinkedList<Restaurante> lista) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> mapa = new HashMap();
    for (Restaurante clave : lista) {
        for (String plato : clave.getPlatosMenu()) {
            int cont = mapa.getOrDefault(plato, 0) + 1; // 1. leer
            mapa.put(plato, cont);                      // 2. luego asignar
        }
    }
    return mapa;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya comprendí el problema y funcionó perfectamente :D @sstan

Answer (score 1):

Nunca estás incrementando el valor de tu variable 'cont'  más allá de 2. Cuando la declaras posee valor 1. Después,  cada vez que existe una coincidencia realizas cont + 1 (que es igual a 2). En caso de tener que haya una tercera iteración del bucle el valor de 'cont'  sigue siendo 1. Deberías aumentar su valor: cont += 1...

```
  if(mapa.containsKey(plato)){ 
                cont += 1;
                mapa.put(plato,cont);
            }
```

Comment: Identificastes bien el problema. Pero la solución va a crear otro problema donde ahora `cont` va a mezclar los valores de diferentes platos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y pues sí resultaba otro problema pero ya está solucionado.